# Does HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap() immutable?

Tags: java

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getSalaries")
public List getSalaries(@RequestParam(value = "id")String id, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ParameterMap parameterMap = (ParameterMap) request.getParameterMap();
    parameterMap.setLocked(false);
    parameterMap.put("id", "b");
    System.out.println(request.getParameterMap().get("id"));
    
    return  null;
}
```

everything is ok , the id was changed. why the id could be changed?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getSalaries")
public List getSalaries(@RequestParam(value = "id")String id, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ParameterMap parameterMap = (ParameterMap) request.getParameterMap();
    parameterMap.setLocked(false);
    System.out.println(request.getParameterMap().get("id"));
    parameterMap.put("id", "b");
    System.out.println(request.getParameterMap().get("id"));
    
    return  null;
}
```

throw the exception: [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No modifications are allowed to a locked ParameterMap] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No modifications are allowed to a locked ParameterMap

because i add the code “request.getParameterMap().get("id")”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem is that you are using the `ParameterMap` the wrong way.

The `ParameterMap` is not *actually* immutable, but you should treat it as immutable.  If you want to mutate it, the correct way to do that is to copy it and then change the copy; e.g. as per @chasing fish's answer.

As you observed, you can call `setLocked(false)` so that you can update the map.  But the problem is that the map you are changing is still shared with the `HttpServletRequest`.  When you call `getParameterMap()` again, the request object helpfully notices that the map is currently unlocked, refreshes it from the source request information, and locks it again.

You can see what is going on by reading the source code; e.g. https://github.com/quickhack/tomcat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java line 1164

You might be able to work around this Tomcat specific behavior, but my advice is don't.  Just treat the object returned by `getParameterMap()` as immutable ... like the Servlet specs say it is.

---

> because I add the code `request.getParameterMap().get("id")`?

Not exactly.  It is because you called `getParameterMap()` twice.  The calls have undocumented side-effects on the state of the parameter map.

Answer (score 0):

> it looks like you are trying to *modify*
> the received form parameters Map, which under Tomcat's interpretation of HTTP request handling is a no-no. (The Servlet Spec 3.0 does not explicitly say so (Chapter 3), but strongly hints in that direction  (there are only "get" methods, no "set" ones).

Maybe you can try:

```
ParameterMap parameterMap = new HashMap(request.getParameterMap())
```

Comment: hi @chasing fish. i just want to verify whether the parameterMap  is immutable.

Comment: In JavaDoc ：* @return an immutable java.util.Map containing parameter names as keys and
     *         parameter values as map values. The keys in the parameter map are
     *         of type String. The values in the parameter map are of type
     *         String array.

Comment: parameterMap.setLocked(false) Is useless.